# Ngrok How can I forward to a specific URL?

Tags: apache, ngrok

I have a web app thats running on local. I try to use ngrok for webhooks but ngrok open the whole app to the world.(I dont want to use **ngrok -auth** because of some reasons.)

I want to ngrok forwards just for webhooks. For example:

```
Forwarding      http://xxxxx.ngrok.io -> localhost:80/webhook
```

Is that possible for ngrok?

Or Can I re-forward ngrok request in apache? I mean;

Ngrok forwards to localhost:80 and apache detect request coming from ngrok and re-forward to localhost:80/webhook.

Answer (score 5):

If you want requests to be forwarded to localhost:80/webhook, then wherever you are specifying the call-back for your service, set it as http://xxxxx.ngrok.io/webhook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://webhookrelay.com and specify the endpoint where you want your webhook to be delivered by appending to this URL:

```
relay forward --bucket my-app http://localhost:80/webhook
```

This way your app will not be exposed to the world. Webhook Relay has two modes:

1. **forward** where it only opens one-way tunnel (nobody can get responses from your app so it's a safe way to deliver webhooks)
2. **connect** where it creates a bidirectional tunnel which is very similar to what ngrok does. It does, however, add a bit more on top of it like let's encrypt certs, basic/token auth and on-the-fly content minification.